# why github said I have file conflict, but my local branch said everything is up to date?

Tags: git, github

Hi I tried to raise PR and github show several of my files are in conflict. so I:
(1) copy the file at remote and compare the file locally they are identical. ( using diff checker)
(2) I did git pull of my local branch and the message said everything is up to date
What else can I do to pass this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A pull request is a merge request between two branches. The conflict is raising cause there are conflicts between the files in your source branch and the files in the destination branch.
So you should pull the destination branch and fix the conflicts locally (by merge or pull --rebase, that's up to you) then push the resolved conflict

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did git pull and it said nothing to commit, working tree clean. (Already up to date). but the message is still there.

Comment: @PChao note the answer says "you should pull the *destination branch*". With `git pull` you are just pulling your own branch.

Comment: oh OK, my mistake let me try that.